# WordPress/Bootstrap mobile menu disappears on scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue on a particular website - http://www.stonecrestre.com - that I've been scratching my head for days now trying to solve.

On mobile when you toggle the menu open it immediately disappears as soon as you start to scroll down. The really weird thing is that it doesn't happen in the Chrome inspector, I can scroll up and down the menu just fine.

Any guidance would be very helpful. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
position: relative;
```

to

```
position: fixed;
```

in your css with the name header.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, that's not the problem I'm having. I realized I worded my question wrong and have fix it. 

The issue I'm having is actually when you toggle the menu open to view the menu items. As soon as you scroll down, it closes. 

Sorry about that!